# Convert svg string to png in Python 2.7

Tags: javascript, python, python-2.7, svg

How can I convert an svg string to png using python?

I have an application consisting of a frontend and a backend (python). In the frontend I draw graphics using d3, and in the backend I eventually create a word document where I want to include the graphic I have created from d3. The api for creating the word document does not support adding svg files, only png, so I need to convert the svg to png. This I do frontend, where I draw the svg to a html canvas, and then convert to a png. However, doing this results in a poor quality png (due to html canvas), so I would want to do this server side so I can keep the high resolution from the svg.

So what I do server side now, is by using StringIO, converting the png string (base64) to a file-like object.

So my question is, how can I convert my svg (js/react) to a png, without noticeable quality loss, using python 2.7?

(I want to keep this in memory the whole time, not writing to a local file)

Comment: why is this down-voted? I don't see what needs to be added?

Comment: I understand. I have edited my question.